# if/else logic - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs

Configuring the backend (AWS) of my React Native app.
npm test coverage.
Test coverage report shows that line 65 is not covered.

```
 service           |    97.5 |    91.67 |     100 |   97.22 |                   
  ...on.service.ts |      96 |       90 |     100 |   95.65 | 65                
  ...am.service.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |
```

Service.ts (else If logic is recently added which is throwing this error)

```
   if (!input.userId) {
        let query = this.model
          .query('appTargetId')
          .eq(appTargetId)
          .where('createDate')
          .ge(fromDate)
          .where('status')
          .not()
          .eq(NotificationStatus.Delete);
          return query.exec();
      }  else if (!input.targetId && input.userId) {
        return this.model                                     //line 65
          .query('appUserId')
          .eq(appUserId)
          .where('createDate')
          .ge(fromDate)
          .where('status')
          .not()
          .eq(NotificationStatus.Delete) 
          .exec();
      }  
      else {
        return this.model
          .query('appUserTargetId')
          .eq(appUserTargetId)
          .where('createDate')
          .ge(fromDate)
          .where('status')
          .not()
          .eq(NotificationStatus.Delete)
          .exec();
      }
    }
```

test:

```
 it('General + Rehab', async () => {
    expect(
      await notificationController.retrieve(
        {
          applicationId,
          targetId: 'B9EF21EE-EA9B-4C9E-9D77-949A7A944AF3',
          requestDate: '2020-04-01T00:00:00.000Z',
        },
        buildRequest({ isAuthorized: false }),
      ),
    ).toHaveLength(3);
  });

  it('General + Personal All Mini App (with userId)', async () => {
    expect(
      await notificationController.retrieve(
        {
          applicationId,
          userId: '2019040913083656642538',
          requestDate: '2020-04-01T00:00:00.000Z',
        },
        buildRequest({ isAuthorized: true }),
      ),
    ).toHaveLength(2);
  });

  it('General + Personal All Mini App', async () => {
    expect(
      await notificationController.retrieve(
        {
          applicationId,
          userId: '2019040913083656642538',
          targetId: 'B9EF21EE-EA9B-4C9E-9D77-949A7A944AF3',
          requestDate: '2020-04-01T00:00:00.000Z',
        },
        buildRequest({ isAuthorized: true }),
      ),
    ).toHaveLength(8);
  });
```

line 65 is not covered. My if/else logic is not in sync. How can I implement this?? Please Help!!!

Comment: all my tests pass successfully but I get an error that line 65 is uncovered. I'm guessing there is some issue with my if/else logic.

Comment: I guess there is. You didn't show test code, which is very relevant here. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem.

Comment: added the code. Please check.

Comment: I don't see the problem with the line you highlighted, test 2 is supposed to cover it. But subApplicationId condition is not covered. It's likely that reported line number is wrong and it actually refers to that condition.

Comment: @EstusFlask could you please check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63030929/index-issue-dynamodb-aws

Comment: @EstusFlask struggling with this from so long man !!

Comment: I'm not sure how the thing is supposed to work in whole because you posted truncated snippets, and I don't use Dynamo myself. But you can debug actual values on your side in case you're unsure how the thing works.